# Splinefun R : how to force interpolated values to be positive, get adjusted value and derivative for the x interpolated

Tags: r, interpolation, spline, derivative

Beginner in R, I performs splinefun function on (x,y) values.  I am searching to get the derivative of the function in x and the interpolated y values by the function. Also, I try to constrain the function to be >0.
Maybe someone already asked these questions ?

I performed the splinefun function, and have the impression that the function is not "smoothing" the values of observed (x,y) but passes exactly through these points. Is it how splinefun interpolates the values, or is there a way to constrain the function to "smooth" the (x,y) cloud?

With what I did, I always have y interpolated = y observed/measured.
Is there something to see with the "method" for the interpolation ("fmm", "monoH.FC",...), or with the "ties" argument?

I also tried to get the first derivative, thanks to the argument "f(x,deriv=1)", but I am not sure this is the right way to do that.

example of the code:

```
x <- c(1,8,14,21,28,35,42,65)
y <- c(65,30,70,150,40,0,15,0)

splinefun(x, y, method="fmm", ties=mean)

deriv <- f(x, deriv=1) #Get the first derivative
y <- f(x) # Get the interpolated y
```

I am searching how to :

1) Force the interpolated function to return a function with values for y only >0 (is there an argument in the splinefun function which handle that ?)

2) Get the values of the derivative of the interpolated function for the x (used for the interpolation)

3) Get the values of the y interpolated (different than the y that was used to perform the interpolation)

Thanks a lot for your help.